# Wrapper for templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

```cpp
// or any templated function
template <typename... Args>
void function(Args... args) {}

// wrapper
void launch(???) { ??? }

int main()
{
    // first option
    launch(function, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    // second option
    launch<function>(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the first option is impossibile since I would have to pass the specialized template function (which I'm trying to avoid).

For the second option I don't know if it's possible, I came up with the following **not working** implementation:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> class Function, typename... Args>
void launch(Args... args)
{
    Function<Args...>(args...);
}
```

which ends up giving me:

```sh
main.cpp:18:5: error: no matching function for call to 'launch'
    launch<function>(1, 2, 3, 4);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Function'
void launch(Args... args)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

So, is something like this even possible?

Comment: Please notice that people keep editing out your tags-in-titles, and stop doing it! Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to infer the type of the callable, as if it was any type, and not care about the template-ness of the thing:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto launch(F f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

It also will forward the return value of the function.

Then, to send your templated function, you must lift the function into a lambda:

```
auto function_lift = [](auto&&... args) 
    noexcept(noexcept(function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)))
    -> decltype(function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))
{
    return function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
};

// also works with defaulted parameters.
launch(function_lift, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Creating those lifted function is very verbose. The answer to verbose-ness in this case is of course a macro:

```
#define LIFT(lift_function) [](auto&&... args)                                \
    noexcept(noexcept(lift_function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)))  \
    -> decltype(lift_function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))         \
{                                                                             \
    return lift_function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);              \
}
```

Now you can call your wrapper:

```
launch(LIFT(function), 5, 4, 3, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You basically cannot do anything with function templates except *call them* (and let arguments get deduced) or *instantiate them* (by manually specifying template arguments).

<sup>I believe there are also niche situations where template arguments may be deduced and a specific instantiation chosen without an actual call, but <s>they don't help here</s> AMA's answer shows how to do that!</sup>

Generic lambdas may or may not help you solve your problem, but you need one such forwarding lambda per function template you want to make "passable":

```
#include <functional>

// or any templated function
template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
void function(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {}

int main()
{
    auto wrapper = [](auto arg1, auto arg2) {
        return function(arg1, arg2);
    };

    std::invoke(wrapper, 1, 2);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/70DU9p)

(Perfect-forwarding to a variadic function with a variadic lambda would be more complicated.)

So you might as well write function templates in the form of functor structs in the first place, or in the form of lambdas returned from non-template functions.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void launch(void(*func)(Args...), Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

calling `launch`:

```
launch(function, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8fab5faaf4ab56a)</kbd>

Comment: Welp, that was simple, but it doesn't work when using functions with default arguments.